# SQL select the first match in an ordered list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 14.0.17213.0

I have a list of events that go in order. I want to select the highest precedent  `acct_no`, `complete_date` and `event`.

My problem is if I use

```
select 
    account_number, event, max(complete_date) as mx_comp
from 
    mytable
where 
    event in ('event1','event2'....)
```

then I get all my `acct_numbers`, all the events in the list and the max complete date for that event.  But I want acct_no listed with the maximum completed date for any item in the list and the associated event.

Furthermore, its wholly possible that two events occurred on the same date, so I cannot do

```
select * 
from mytable mt
join
    (select acct_number, max(complete_date) 
     from mytable) t on mt.acct_number = t.account_number 
                     and mt.complete_date = t.complete_date
```

because if two events occurred on the same day then I still get duplicate results.

I have tried to do a similar thing with

```
    row_number() over (order by account_number) as RowNum
```

but it did not work, because I still get matches to all the events, not just my highest precedence event

it really boils down to needing to return the acct_number, event and complete date associated to the highest importance match from items in an ordered list.

I am sure it is easy - I just cannot seem to figure it out and despite all my google and stack searching I simply cannot figure it out

I have recently been thinking that it might be possible with something like coalesce(mylist) because I would be able to put my list in order but I cannot figure out how to use coalesce in a meaningful way for this problem.

The real solution would be to create a table with precedence numbers or have a most recent indicator but I dont have unlimited access to create any tables I want.

Any help or ideas on how to match to an ordered list would be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by account_number order by complete_date desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
      where event in ('event1', 'event2', ....)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```